# How do I run specific scenario in cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

How to run specific scenario in cucumber out of multiple scenario?

**Feature file**

```
Feature: Test Test Smoke scenario

  Scenario: Test login with valid credentials
    Given open firefox and start application
```

jhbhhjhj
When I click on Login
And enter valid "kumar.rakesh@yopmail.com" and valid "admin@123"
Then Click on login and User should be able to login successfully

```
  Scenario: Test shop for cart
    Given Click on shop for carts
    And select plates
    When Click on Add to cart
    Then product should be added in the cart successfully
    And verify the product
    
Scenario: Test login with valid credentials1
    Given open firefox and start application
    When I click on Login
    And enter valid "kumar.rakesh@yopmail.com" and valid "admin@123"
    Then Click on login and User should be able to login successfully

  Scenario: Test shop for cart1
    Given Click on shop for carts
    And select plates
    When Click on Add to cart
    Then product should be added in the cart successfully
    And verify the product
```

**Test Runner**

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(features="features",glue={"steps"},format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"})

public class TestRunnr {

}
```

Comment: Beside all the valid answers below you can select a single scenario using the `features` parameter together with a line number like: `features= "src/main/resources/publish/Login.feature:17"` to only run the scenario which starts in line *17* (with `Scenario: ...`)

Answer (score 7):

Use tags future in the cucumber like below.

```
Feature: Test Milacron Smoke scenario

  @Test1
  Scenario: Test login with valid credentials
    Given open firefox and start application
    When I click on Login
    And enter valid "kumar.rakesh@thoughtfocus.com" and valid "Thought@123"
    Then Click on login and User should be able to login successfully

  @Test2
  Scenario: Test shop for cart
    Given Click on shop for carts
    And select plates
    When Click on Add to cart
    Then product should be added in the cart successfully
    And verify the product

  @Test3
  Scenario: Test login with valid credentials1
    Given open firefox and start application
    When I click on Login
    And enter valid "kumar.rakesh@thoughtfocus.com" and valid "Thought@123"
    Then Click on login and User should be able to login successfully

  @Test4
  Scenario: Test shop for cart1
    Given Click on shop for carts
    And select plates
    When Click on Add to cart
    Then product should be added in the cart successfully
    And verify the product
```

If you want to run only Test1 scenario update runner file like below.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="features",glue={"steps"},format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"},tags={"@Test1"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

If you want to execute multiple scenarios keep comma sepearated tags as mentioned below.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features="features",glue={"steps"},format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"},tags={"@Test1,@Test2"})
    public class TestRunner {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the other answers suggest, use tags. If you use maven, you don't have to change the runner file - just add this to your maven call

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @Test1"
```

The thing I like about this method is that I don't risk committing the tags in the runner file.

Also, here is an example on running multiple tags in maven.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use selective feature file or selective scenarios in the feature using tags. Please try with this solution.

Lets consider the you have n number of feature files and you need to run only selective feature from that. Then name each feature file with @tag name.

eg.: Under this folder, if you are having n number of features - "src/main/resources/publish"

## 1st Feature file name:

Login.feature

//Inside the file start with feature tag name

```
@Login
Feature: To Login to Email

//Then feature name followed with scenario tag name
@User1

#Scenario1:
Scenario Outline: Navigate and logon to gmail application

Given User launches gmail application
When User updates emailID <emailID>
And User updates pwd <pwd>    
Then User clicks on Login Button


Examples: 
  | emailID    | pwd |
  | a@gmail.com| 123 | 


@User2

#Scenario2:
Scenario Outline: Navigate and logon to facebook application

//Write the code for scenario 2 as similar to above
```

## 2nd Feature File name:

CreateEmail.feature

```
@Createmail
Feature: Create email

Scenario: Blah blah blah...

//Write all Given when And Then
```

## 3rd Feature File name:

SendEmail.feature

```
@Sendemail
Feature: Send email

Scenario: Blah blah blah...

//Write all Given when And Then
```

So From the above Test files. Lets consider you want to test 1st and 3rd feature alone, Then you can use code as below:

eg.:

//This is to run specific feature files, which is 1 and 3. Likewise you can use the tags for scenario as well if you have n number scenario in same feature file.

```
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish", tags="@Login, @Sendemail",  format = {"pretty"} )
```

// This is to run specific scenario in the feature file. If you have multiple scenario, then you can write your specify your scenario tags followed by comma.

```
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish/Login.feature", tags="@User2",  format = {"pretty"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tags to filter out the scenario. Put the tag on the feature file and add this to the cucumberoptions of the runner.

```
@RunScenarioExample
Scenario: Test login with valid credential

@Cucumber.Options(features="features",glue={"steps"},format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"}, tags={"@RunScenarioExample"})
```